# Quarkus - Smallrye Override Warning during Server-Start

Tags: quarkus

When i start the quarkus-server i get following logging-outputs during startup:

```
> Task :fk_backend:quarkusDev
io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-net::jar classpath entry /home/funkrusher/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.smallrye.common/smallrye-common-net/2.2.0/261d912ae8bc78a67df97e69a589f998440f6d1c/smallrye-common-net-2.2.0.jar was overriden with /home/funkrusher/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.smallrye.common/smallrye-common-net/2.1.2/67e1ba3435161b43d214dc217590ee9f9c496896/smallrye-common-net-2.1.2.jar
...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

The warning states:

- classpath entry smallrye-common-net-2.2.0.jar was overriden with smallrye-common-net-2.1.2.jar

So it seems that the running quarkus-server will use version 2.1.2 instead of 2.2.0 of the smallrye library stated here.

---

I created my quarkus project via quarkus-cli as follows:

```
quarkus create app my-groupId:my-artifactId --extensions=resteasy-reactive,resteasy-reactive-jackson --gradle
```

I have not changed anything with this default configuration created by the quarkus-cli

When i analyze the gradle dependencies via following command:

```
./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency smallrye-common-net --configuration runtimeClasspath
```

i get:

```
io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-net:2.1.2
\--- io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.8.2
     \--- runtimeClasspath (requested io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:{strictly 3.8.2})

io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-net:2.2.0 -> 2.1.2
\--- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager:3.0.4.Final
     +--- io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.8.2
     |    \--- runtimeClasspath (requested io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:{strictly 3.8.2})
```

can someone point me to the correct fix to solve this problem?

The following Quarkus-Version is used:

- 3.8.2